# Linux octal permision addition and subtract explanation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, octal

I have been looking for an explanation for linux permission using Octal numbers, and I have found nothing.

I know in octal if I have a file (called file) with 555 permission (5 for user, 5 for group and 5 for others), if I execute **chmod +200 file** I can see new permission 755. If I do a subtract i get the same; but how can I do a mix permission change. I mean, how can I change file permision from 555 to 721 using an octal chmod command?

I need to do that with additions and subtracts in Octal... I mean I must do a chmod +200 (filename) and then chmod -034 (filename) commands... Is there any command to do it only with one command like chmod +2-34 (filename)???

Thanks a lot

Comment: simply chmod 721 <filename>

Comment: `chmod +2-34 (filename)` isn't possible. You'll have to write your own wrapper script that does this "math" and then call `chmod` with the result. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add or subtract to get your desired result:

```
chmod 721 (filename)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just do 
   chmod 721 file
This will result 
(111,010,001) which is 721